# Make two arrays start at the same time

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, gsap

I have two arrays contains several movie clips. I used for loop to inject first array in timeline object successfully. But then I realized, what the hack I will do about the second array  I need to start them simultaneously, and every array must have different destination at x and y.

Imagine banner 745x100px, I need to animate different movie clips from sides to some destination.

code example:

```
import com.greensock.*;
import com.greensock.easing.*;
import flash.display.MovieClip;


var mainArray:Array = [amcMC, tantrumMC, blokMC, misMC, futMC, laoMC, cauMC, deepMC, plusMC, noMC, copMC ];
var therapyArray:Array = [kurtenMC, panacMC, dubMC, lowMC, dtoxMC, hunMC, mopMC, zenMC, hanMC, conMC ];

var timeline:TimelineMax = new TimelineMax({repeat:-1});

for(var key:String in mainArray){
   var mcMain:MovieClip = MovieClip(mainArray[key]);
   timeline.append(TweenMax.from(mcMain,1 ,{x:-200 y: 40, scaleX:0.1, blurFilter:{blurX:20}, ease:Back.easeOut}));
   timeline.append(TweenMax.to(mcMain,cas,{x:-200, y: 40, delay:1, blurFilter:{blurX:20}, ease:Back.easeOut}));   
}
```

I need to apply slightly different tweens on second array and trigger them simultaneously, or with small offset.

Answer (score 2):

Use insertMultiple. This allows you to add multiple tweens at the same point in the timeline. You can even use settings to space them out evenly with equal delays if you like using this method.

here is an example:

```
var timeline:TimelineMax = new TimelineMax({repeat:2, yoyo:true, repeatDelay:1.5});
timeline.append( TweenLite.from(blackBar, 0.8, {x:550}) );
timeline.insertMultiple( TweenMax.allFrom([logo, timelineWord, maxWord, byGreenSock], 0.5, {autoAlpha:0}, 0.25), 0.6);
timeline.insertMultiple( TweenMax.allFrom(lettersArray, 1, {y:"-30", alpha:0, ease:Elastic.easeOut}, 0.04), 1.4);
```

from the greensock docs:

> insertMultiple() and appendMultiple() provide some very powerful
>   sequencing capabilities, allowing you to add an Array of tweens (using
>   TweenLite/Max instances or the new shorthand syntax, like [mc, 1,
>   {x:100}]) and optionally align them with SEQUENCE or START modes, and
>   even stagger them if you want. For example, to insert 3 tweens into
>   the timeline, aligning their start times but staggering them by 0.2
>   seconds,

and the link to the docs here:
http://www.greensock.com/as/docs/tween/_timelinemax.html

Comment: Would you mind clicking accept if this is the answer you choose? It will keep the question from appearing as open, and help people doing searches to find the answer that worked.

Answer (score 1):

You can use 2 TimelineMax objects along with a Timer. Add a listener to the timer that when called would load the 2nd TimelineMax with the 2nd array. Your offset would be whatever you set the timer delay to.